# DataSource and ByteArrayDataSource not compatiable?

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
InputStream imageStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("email/logo.png");
DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(IOUtils.toByteArray(imageStream), "image/png");
```

Which throws me an error of:

> Error:(65, 30) java: incompatible types: javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource cannot be converted to org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource
>   Error:(66, 44) java: no suitable constructor found for DataHandler(org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource)
>       constructor javax.activation.DataHandler.DataHandler(javax.activation.DataSource) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource cannot be converted to javax.activation.DataSource)
>       constructor javax.activation.DataHandler.DataHandler(java.net.URL) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource cannot be converted to java.net.URL)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to achieve, which makes it very hard to help you. Are you sure you actually want to be using `org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource`? Perhaps you really want `javax.activation.DataSource` instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thats was it!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have wrong imports.
You are trying to cast `javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource` to `org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.DataSource`. Check your imports.